# DCPU-16 DIV instruction

Tags: assembly, dcpu-16

I'm looking at the [specification](http://0x10c.com/doc/dcpu-16.txt) for the DCPU-16 and I'm having trouble understanding the purpose of the overflow value with the DIV instruction:

> DIV a, b - sets a to a/b, sets O to ((a<<16)/b)&0xffff.

Can anybody explain the semantic meaning of O here, what it would be useful for?

Comment: I'd argue it's worse than useless, with 'O' requiring a 32/16-bit division! Setting 'O' to the remainder would have been more useful, and made multiple-precision arithmetic easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like O gives the fractional part of the result (as a fixed-point number). For example, consider 5 / 2:

```
a = 5 / 2 = 2 (integer part)
O = ((5 << 16) / 2) & 0xffff = (327680 / 2) & 0xffff = 32768
```

If you consider O as the 16 binary fractional digits, then this represents the 0.5 fractional part of the result.

Another way of looking at it is the binary result in bits is:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
```

5 / 2 is

```
0000000000000010.1000000000000000
```

As you can tell by inspection, that result is 5 (101 binary) shifted right by one bit into the fractional bits.

Answer (score 2):

`((a<<16)/b)` will give you the 16-bit fractional portion of the division.

It's easier to see in base-10:  If we want to find the first three fractional-digits of, say, 5/3, we can move 5 three places over (5000), divide that by 3, then take the last three whole digits.  5000/3 is 1666, so the first three digits after the decimal of 5/3 are .666.

---

This works because "moving 5 one digit over" is the same as "multiplying by 10", and multiplication/division are commutative (the order can be swapped around), so `(5 * 1000) / 3` = `(5 / 3) * 1000` = `1.6666... * 1000` = `1666.666...`.

In other words, shifting 5 over a few digits and dividing by 3 is the same as shifting (5/3) by a couple of digits.